# setTimeout inside forloop? JS NODEJS

Tags: node.js, for-loop, delay, settimeout

I'm trying to create a delay between every loop. However I'm always ending up with only with delay before loop is being fired. Way i was doing it was the following:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
      setTimeout(function()
      {
        console.log(i + ". " + items[i]['name']);
        priceManagement.FindPrices(items[i]['name']);
      }, 3000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
      setTimeout(function(i)
      {
        console.log(i + ". " + items[i]['name']);
        priceManagement.FindPrices(items[i]['name']);
      }, 3000*i, i);
    }
```

Or can pass the `items[i]['name']` as a parameter as well:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
      setTimeout(function(i, name)
      {
        console.log(i + ". " + name);
        priceManagement.FindPrices(name);
      }, 3000*i, i, items[i]['name']);
    }
```

And I recommend you to read this: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/

Comment: It kinda worked, however it's being looped on the last integer, and it can't reach content of 'items' variable.

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your main loop is executing `setTimeout` functions continuously. Due to the **async** nature of this function, you will expect to see the function being executed without delay between them.

You can use `setInterval` if you want approximate effect, when the executing time of the function is *much* less than the delay time. This will achieve the same with Adam's anwer.

But for the exact "create a delay between every loop", you will need some call backs.

First come in mind:

```
function main() {
  doWork(items, 0, items.length);
}

function doWork(items, i, loopLength) {
  // The bit in the loop
  console.log(i + ". " + items[i]['name']);
  priceManagement.FindPrices(items[i]['name']);
  i++;

  if (i < loopLength) {
    delayDoWork(items, i, loopLength);
  }
  else {
    // Do rest in the main
    ...
  }
}

function delayDoWork(items, i, loopLength) {
  setTimeout(function(items, i, loopLength)
  {
    doWork(items, i, loopLength);
  }, 3000, items, i, loopLength);
}
```

This will guarantee the exact delay between loops.

**EDIT**

You may want to do more experiment for this, as I'm not an expert knowing how `setInterval` is designed to work in JS, as it's not multi threading in nature? Start point will be considering the quote below from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/2710486)

> In actuality, setTimeout() re-queues the new JavaScript at the end of the execution queue.

Comment: right, that's another way, and I was aware of this. However it requires more code, and I was curious why this isn't working as I expected it to, as in different programming languages I've never had similar problem. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: I'm not a complete JS guy either. Cheers :)